# Django: dependent dropdown

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm a newbie and trying to make my own dependent dropdown through javascrip and I'm kind of stuck.

I have 2 regions, `A REGION` with the id of `1` and `B REGION` with the id of `2`,

I have 4 cities, `A CITY` and `B CITY` which have a foreign key of `1` and `C CITY` and `D CITY` have the foreign key of `2`. I have noticed that whenever it loops it leaves `B CITY` and `D CITY` which have the foreign key of `1` and `2`.

Also is there a better option than using `.remove` as it permanently deletes the `<options>`.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance.

My html

```
<select id="region" name="region">
        <option id = 0 >-----</option>
        {% for item in region %}
            <option id = {{ item.id }}>{{ item.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
 </select>

<select id="city" name="city">
        <option id = 0>-----</option>
        {% for item in city %} 
            <option id = {{ item.reg }}>{{ item.name }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
</select>
```

and my script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#source").change(function() {
        var region = $(this);
        var city = document.getElementById("status")
        var i = 1;
        while (i < city.length) {
            if (city.options[i].val != region.val()){
                city.options[i].remove();
                i++;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is my models

```
class REGION(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)

class CITY(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    reg = models.ForeignKey("REGION")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return u'%s' % (self.name)
```

Comment: You should build a hash in javascript, the keys are regions, the values are a list of cities for the region. When your `change` event is triggered, you can just loop up your data structure to pull all cities, then replace the city dropdown with the cities you got.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I solved my problem (if you want to use javascript)

First of all here is my html

```
<select id="region" name="region">
    <option id = 0 >-----</option>
    {% for item in region %}
        <option id = {{ item.id }}>{{ item.name }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>

<select id="city" name="city">
    <option id = 0>-----</option>
</select>
```

Instead of `.remove` I used `.append`

My javascript

```
$("#source").change(function() {
     el = $(this);
     var select = document.getElementById("city");
     $("#city").val([]);
     select.length = 0;
     $("#city").append("<option>-----</option>");

     <!--This part deletes all records in preparation for new results-->


     var reg = [{% for item in city %}"{{ item.reg }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];
     var name = [{% for item in city %}"{{ item.name }}"{% if not forloop.last %},{% endif %}{% endfor %}];

     <!--Storing all data in an array-->

     for(var i = 0; i<reg.length; i++){
         if(el.val() == reg[i]){
             $("#status").append("<option id = "+ reg[i] +" value = \"" + name[i] + "\">" + name[i] + "</option>");
         }

      }
});
```

Thanks for the Answer Shang Wang